# How do you add a model method to an existing class within an interactive session (in iPython)?

Tags: python, django, ipython

I have a basic model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = USStateField()
```

I start up an iPython session with:

```
$ python manage.py shell
>>> from app.models import Person
```

How do I add this model method within the iPython session?

```
>>>    def is_midwestern(self):  
...        "Returns True if this person is from the Midwest."  
...        return self.state in ('IL', 'WI', 'MI', 'IN', 'OH', 'IA', 'MO')  

>>> person = Person.objects.filter(last_name='Franklin')
>>> person.is_midwestern
True
```

I want to be able to test these model methods without having to add the method to the models.py file and then restarting the iPython shell session.

I seem to be doing something wrong because when I add a new model method in an interactive session, it doesn't seem to be linked to the class like it does when the model method is defined in a file.

So if I created the model method as above and attempted to use it. 
e.g. 
' >>> person = Person.objects.filter(last_name='Franklin')
`>>> person.is_midwestern

'Person' object has no attribute`'is_midwestern'`

Comment: Not clear what u want. ipython emulates python shell. So it cant be different than otherwise. Explain better.

Comment: On a semi-unrelated note, I think you're missing a good chunk of the Midwestern states.

Comment: When I add a new model method in an interactive session, it doesn't seem to be linked to the class like it does when the model method is defined in a file.

So if I created the model method as above and attempted to use it.
e.g.
' >>> person = Person.objects.filter(last_name='Franklin')
`>>> person.is_midwestern
'Person'  object has no attribute 'is_midwestern'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

why can't you just do this
Person.is_midwestern = is_miswestern e.g.

```
>>> class Person:
...     def __init__(self): self.mid = True
... 
>>> def is_midwestern(self): return self.mid
... 
>>> Person.is_midwestern = is_midwestern
>>> p = Person()
>>> p.is_midwestern()

True
>>>
```

Comment: It looks like it doesn't work under python 3:
`method() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer gave me an error, but from [this blog post](http://block.arch.ethz.ch/blog/2016/07/adding-methods-to-python-classes/), I used the following method and it worked.

```
from types import MethodType
Person.is_midwestern = MethodType(is_midwestern, p)
```